# Is anyone a Node.js developer using elementary OS?

Tags: software-installation, development, web-development, python

I am moving from Mac after 10 years and have chosen to go with Linux for both my desktop and laptop.

I currently have Ubuntu 16.04 running and with a few visual tweaks I really like it. I have seen both Deepin 15.5 and elementary OS and both really appeal to me visually.

I just wondered if any node.js devs are using either distro and what their thoughts are? Is it a stable env for node development? I am mainly using React front ends with express APIs. But on the side I do like to play with Python3 too. Mongo is my main DB. Any advice or feedback would be awesome.

I use VS Code on Ubuntu and works fine so I am assuming it would on elementary too?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I develop for `Node`, and `React` using EOS, I use Sublime Text usually, but I have VS Code installed too. I've used that for Golang and opened node projects with it. It works well.

The terminal is great, although I still install `oh-my-zsh` for the shell. Node itself runs well, and frankly I find open source development tools are great in Linux.

As for MongoDB, Postgres and other tools - all work well too. Personally I prefer to run them (for app development) inside docker, so I can keep them isolated, switch local ports, and start and stop the DBs for different projects, as well as easily use whatever versions I like without having to install the OS packages.

Python 3 I use all the time, as well as 2.7 for one project. I have iPython notebooks running and pretty much anything I used on a Mac I have here too.

I'd say go for it.

Comment: Awesome - that is what I was looking for. I will get going in the laptop this week and once I am settled in will change over the desktop env too. I appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

While I don't develop with node on elementary. I do develop android using java and kotlin. Being built upon ubuntu 16.04 it's super stable and any apps available on ubuntu are available on elementary.

I wouldn't recommend deepin. With the latest release they now track all your activity.

Comment: Thanks Sean, I have seen this mentioned with Deepin today. So I think my choice is down to elementary :) I have a new laptop coming this week so I think I will try out elementary as my distro on that and see how it goes